# Excluding DateTimes within a range

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I would like some clarification on the accuracy of my datetime range logic, I want to exclude any dates from available that live within a date range of an unavailable date.

i.e. if Start 17/10/2018 - 22:35 || End 17/10/2018 23:00 was an unavailable date, then result should not contain any objects who's Start and End properties reside between these two DateTimes.

Thanks

```
var unavailable = new List<obj>();
var available = new List<obj>();

var result = available.Where(x => !unavailable.Any(y => y.Start > x.Start && y.End < 
x.End);

public class obj 
{
   public DateTime Start {get; set;}
   public DateTime End {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with at least 6 different sample inputs and the expected results for each of those sample inputs. _At least one of those sample inputs should cover the scenario where the available entry has a `Start` between an unavailable `Start` and `End` and the available `End` is **after** the unavailable `End`._

Comment: I'd also recommend changing the class name from `obj` to something more useful (maybe `Appointment`?).

Comment: You probably want >= and <=. Otherwise, a date range that exactly coincides with the start or end of an unavailable range will still be considered available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your overlapping logic is flawed. Do it like (touching edges exclusive):

```
var result = available.Where(x => 
     !unavailable.Any(y => y.Start < x.End && y.End > x.Start));

public class DateRange // obj is awkward naming 
{
   public DateTime Start {get; set;}
   public DateTime End {get; set;}
}
```